# Focus on `InputField` upon creation?

Tags: inputfield

Let's say we create an input field as

```
InputField[]
```

After hitting enter, the input field appears in the output area below, however the focus in the notebook jumps straight to the next line, where a new cell can be created. Is there a way to create an `InputField` and immediately select it into focus upon creation (without having to click on it), so that text can be immediately typed into the `InputField`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can assign a box id to an input field using `BoxID -> "id"` and use the function `` FrontEnd`MoveCursorToInputField `` to move the focus to the desired input field:

```
InputField[Null, BoxID -> "id"]
FrontEnd`MoveCursorToInputField[EvaluationNotebook[], "id"];
```

[image]

Another example:

```
Grid[{{InputField[Dynamic[x]], InputField[Dynamic[y], BoxID -> "ify"],
    InputField[Dynamic[z]]}}]
FrontEnd`MoveCursorToInputField[EvaluationNotebook[], "ify"];
```

[image: ![enter image description here]

[image]

Alternatively, highlight the cell contents and use `Ctrl` + `Shift` + `Enter` to evaluate in place:

[image]