# How to automatically put the keyboard focus in the InputField of a newly created dialog window?

Tags: inputfield, dialog-window

Suppose I want my code to pop up a dialog window containing an `InputField` and automatically put the keyboard focus there so it's ready and waiting to accept user input.

I wondered about that.

It's not hard to find multiple StackExchange entries showing that others wondered the same thing (e.g., [How to set focus of a dialog window?](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/228667/focus-on-inputfield-upon-creation?noredirect=1&lq=1)).

I looked at but was not satisfied with the answers so I came up with my own, which is described below.

Comment: If you are not happy with given answers you can add yours, isn't this topic a duplicate? You can make it less duplicate but explaining why do we need a separate one.

Comment: Btw, your answer does not work for me, maybe OS/race condition dependent. The caret is not shown in the input field. And I guess the SelectionMove approach will need to be adapted if the layout of the dialog changes, right? Additionally, it does not handle Cancel/Close.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback.
#1. I didn't regard the topic as a duplicate because the previous related entries that I found seemed similar but IMHO not quite the same. FWIW, also pretty old.
#2. I just verified that the method works on versions 11.3, 12.0, 12.1, 12.2, 12.3, 13.0, and 13.01, but, alas, fails on 13.1. Apparently something changed. Maybe there's a fix but I haven't found it yet.

Comment: The point is that the question sounds like a duplicate and if you object I'd like you to explain why.

Comment: Fine. Feel free to mark this as a duplicate of some very old questions that have been closed.

Comment: I was thinking about one of those which are linked there and are open. And about moving your answer there so that everything is in one place.

Answer (score 1):

Running the demo code below pops up a dialog window with an `InputField` that returns a `String`. The combined effect of the two `SelectionMove` commands is to put the focus inside the `InputField`. The `While` step spin-waits until an acceptable input has been entered. After that normal execution proceeds.

```
Module[{nb},
  Clear[newName];
  nb =
   CreateDialog[
    Column[{TextCell["Enter new name", 20], 
      Row[{InputField[Dynamic[newName], String, Alignment -> Right]}, 
       BaseStyle -> 16, Alignment -> Center],
      DefaultButton[DialogReturn[]]}, Alignment -> Center],
    Modal -> True(* Block other Mathematica windows until closed. *)
    ];
  (* Move window focus to input field, then wait until new name has been entered. *)
  SelectionMove[nb, Before, CellContents];
  SelectionMove[nb, Next, TextLine];
  While[Not[StringQ[newName]]]
];
Print["Proceed with newName = ", newName]
```

Tested in Mathematica v12.xx and v13.xx